# I want to display the images and videos from firebase to a Listview

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I have uploaded 3 photos and one video into firebase I want to display there when the user clicks on the menu that have view button to show the images and the video how can i implement this in my application cause when i click on the menu it display there is no photo exist but the images and video uploaded successfully here is my itemView

```
class ImageVideosWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final String imagepath;
final String mediaPath; // Can be image or video
final String placeHolder;
final Future<void> Function()? onTap;

const ImageVideosWidget({
Key? key,
required this.imagepath,
required this.mediaPath,
required this.placeHolder,
this.onTap,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocBuilder<VideoPlayerCubit, VideoState>(
  builder: (context, videoState) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 120,
            offset: const Offset(0, 10),
          ),
        ],
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 18),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(placeHolder),
            const SizedBox(width: 12),
            Text(
              'providedImage.png',
              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                fontSize: 13,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: const Color(0xFF046AB2),
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Row(
              children: [
                PopupMenuButton(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: isArabic()
                            ? const Text('عرض')
                            : const Text('View'),
                        onTap: () {
                          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return Dialog(
                                  child:
                                      PhotoViewWidget(imageUrl: imagepath),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                          child: isArabic()
                              ? const Text('حذف')
                              : const Text('Delete'),
                          onTap: onTap),
                    ];
                  },
                  onSelected: (value) {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

this my screen that shows the items

```
 BlocBuilder<ReachedUploadCubit, ReachedUploadState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ImagePicked) {
              files = state.media;
            } else if (state is ImageUploadInProgress) {
              return const LinearProgressIndicator();
            } else if (state is ImageUploadFailure) {
              return Text(state.error);
            } else if (state is ImageUploadSuccess) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 600,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 4, // The number of items
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ImageVideosWidget(
                      imagepath: state.downloadUrl[index],
                      mediaPath: '',
                      placeHolder: 'assets/image_placeholder.svg',
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else if (state is ReachedUploadInitial) {
              return Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset('assets/rounded.svg'),
                  InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await context
                            .read<ReachedUploadCubit>()
                            .pickMedia();
                        context
                            .read<ReachedUploadCubit>()
                            .stream
                            .listen((state) {
                          if (state is ImagePicked) {
                            files = state.media;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/imageUpload.svg')),
                ],
              );
            }
            return Container();
          },
        )
```

Comment: You can use `StreamBuilder` to show your image and videos  that you upload on fireBase. Firebase kind of works instantly to fetch your data from the cloud  because of `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Your flutter code seem to be fine.
Are you sure your images are reachable, in firebase storage section look for the url like :

```
 https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT_NAME/o/LOCATION?alt=media&token=TOKEN
```

Maybe you can try to add an image on any screen to test if they are reachable.